# Edit my pending edit?

Tags: support, edits

I recently made an edit to someone's question, the edit is now pending, but I noticed I forgot to wrap a piece of code into code tags. I tried to fix this but can't find where/if I can edit my pending edits. Is this possible? And if so, where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find on your account **Activity -> all actions -> suggestion**

Under the **suggestion** tab, all your suggested edits will be available, you can select and update that.

Direct link for your account's suggested edit tab: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7098649/metoniem?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

You can click the expected question's link from the list of edits, and it will navigate to the corresponding post. If the question is still in peer review, you can use the *edit* link below the post to make updates.

Comment: I know I can find my suggested edits there, but I still don't see where to update my own suggested edit before it's being approved/rejected.

Comment: @Metoniem Clicking on the question link from this tab, it will navigates to the question you expect to edit. If it is still in reviewing, you can edit the post, it will allow.

Comment: @Metoniem just hit edit on the question/answer again. Should take you to your edit so you can make further changes.