# How can I see all my pending reviews?

Tags: support, feature-request

I haven't found yet a way to see all my pending edit (only pending ones).

I know I can see my edits by going to *my profile view* **>** *Activity* **>** *all actions* **>** *suggestions* (as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343412/can-i-see-my-rejected-edits) which is similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253684/can-i-see-my-edits) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343385/edit-my-pending-edit)) but **I cannot**, for instance, **filter** only the pending one.

I ask this because lately I see [Suggested edit queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) and I found it very tedious to go through all of my edits to see if I really have so many pending edits (even though I only have 4 pages right now, this will increase for sure in the future).

It would be nice to have a filter option here.

It was pointed out that the pending reviews queue is site-wide; every single person can have up to 5 pending reviews, so this question is "how to see those 5 pending edits of mine".

Comment: You can only have 5 pending edits. You will probably find these are quite close to the top of page 1 when looking in your _suggestions_.

Comment: Doing some more research I found [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45756/my-accepted-edits) which can be very helpful. It would be nice to have that like a filter on SO. I just don't how would that impact performance.

Comment: Point of clarification, it's not *your* queue that's full it's the Suggested Edit queue for the whole site.

Comment: Thanks, @Bugs, for pointing that out, when I posted this question I was seeing only one pending review at the top of the list. That's why I supposed that maybe another ones were on the other pages, but seeing the comment posted by BSMP I understand now :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your pending edits are listed in the ["all actions" (sub-tab) ➞ "suggestions" (sub-sub-tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640649/lealceldeiro?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) in the [activity (tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640649/lealceldeiro?tab=topactivity) for your account.

[image: "all actions" (sub-tab) ➞ "suggestions" (sub-sub-tab)]

Pending edits will *not* show the text "Approve" or "Reject" in the entry for the suggested edit. They will *tend* to be near the top of the list, but could be anywhere, depending on your edit suggestion history. In general, edits to tag wiki/tag excerpts tend to take substantially longer to be approved, so those are more likely to be further down the list, or even on a page other than page 1.

Comment: But as far as I can tell, there's no way to filter (or group) only pending edits. Or am I just not seeing it? That'd be helpful.

Comment: @shaedrich As far as I know, there isn't a way to do that with the stock interface. On and off, I'm working on a userscript which allows you to sort that table and most other tables on the site, which would give you at least the grouping you're asking for. Unfortunately, I've encountered what appears to be a bug in Tampermonkey (the most popular userscript manager), which results in substantial issues under some conditions (e.g. all userscripts on the pages it loads on stop working upon restarting the browser), so it may be a bit before I figure out what's causing that, fix it, and release it.