# 5 pending edits appears to be too much

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Since maybe one or two weeks I can see up to four pending edit suggestions of mine in the  profile:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4489263/stefan-wuebbe?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
Then the next edit attempt would cause a red "You have too many pending edits.." alert.

What I tried is going back in the "Suggestions" history, and looking for a "view pending edits only" SO feature that I did not find.
[How can I see all my pending reviews?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346511/how-can-i-see-all-my-pending-reviews)
Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: Yeah, uh, that post does seem to make the not-necessarily-valid assumption that all your pending edits are _recent_, which is...not necessarily the case, especially with tag-wiki edits.

Comment: It's also for a previous, clearer version of that page.  The new one, aggravatingly, no longer shows _anything_ for pending edits; just the lack of a result.

Comment: Hmm... it also does not say "pending edit" any longer they just don't show a resolution Accept or Reject.

Comment: I have browsed down to page 21 once and page 16 twice (the last sweep of which included a ctrl-f to make sure I couldn't miss it), and I can't find the last review. My money is on deletion weirdness

Comment: To confirm: at this current moment, can you suggest edits?  And please confirm the exact error text you receive.

Comment: You're not trying to edit a tag wiki are you? That requires two edit slots, one for the usage guidance and one for the wiki.

Comment: @RobertLongson Per [the rate-limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/165261), you *can* suggest tag wiki edits with 4 pending edits, which puts you at 6 - that being the only way you can have more than 5.

Comment: @RyanM sure, unless the problem is that that's broken.

Comment: Ah, well that could be.  That would also be good to confirm.

Comment: @RyanM, I tried and failed in the same minute when I was writing this question and the first half of the red-alert message is exactly quoted. And it was not a Tag Wiki thing. Will start to try finding something to 5th-edit right now

Comment: Yes, failed right now, red-alerting "You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved." in https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33136017

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a bug.

Comment: Just noticed I can have 5 pending edits again, that's great, thanks a lot to whom it may concern

Answer (score 2):

First Use the [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4489263/stefan-wuebbe?tab=activity&sort=reviews) Tab

Then comes there should be a Pending selection in the sub section for the Reviews.

Same should be applicable in All tabs.

It makes life easy to categorize/search the data, and saves time.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. With 1.7k reputation I had seen the "Reviews" Tab but no "Pending" selection there.

Comment: There is no review tab, at least not for users below 1k reputation?